# How can I switch my 1 1/2 year yorkie from toileting on a pad to going outside?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

My yorkie was pad trained when I got her at 3 months. She did good for 2 months without poop and peeing around house, then out of no where she starting pooping right in front of us. If she pee on pad, she don't want to poop on there, she will go next to pad.

I want to train her to go outside, but don't know where to start. I tried moving pad to door, but she then started pooping anywhere. When I take her out, she won't go. She will come right in house and poop and pee.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the approach for training cats to do tricks, gradually shaping the behavior,  might work...

She already knows the pad. Move the pad *slowly* to and out the door, a foot or two every few days, so she is always going go where she found the pad last time and can find it from there. If she seems to be getting the idea you might be able to move faster; if she objects because it isn't where it's supposed to be you may need to slow down or take a step back. Once you get her outside you can start reducing the size of the pad to transition her to grass.

Or go back to the puppy-training approach: feed and water, then take her outside on leash and keep her company until she has to go, then praise/reward her effusively.

You've trained her to a specific location and cue, and she's trying to obey. Now you need to retrain to tell her that outdoors is ok too... and that's going to require convincing her to break the previous training before you can confirm that, yes, this is ehat you want her to do.